# Prevent user from executing a shell command

Tags: command-line

How can I prevent a none root user to executes e.g. the `passwd` command in terminal?

Comment: The question is not well-posed. Do you want that the user shouldn't execute any command that needs sudo? Or just that specific command?

Comment: @dadexix86 It's fine. The OP wants to keep users from changing their passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a user from running the passwd command, just make it non-executable for everyone but root.

```
sudo chmod o-x /usr/bin/passwd
```

An odd request though. You usually want users to be able to change their password, and to do it regularly. Also, the passwd command isn't the only way a user can change their own password...

Comment: Thanks. It was more a general question on how to prevent a none root user to execute a shell command.

Answer (score -1):

With **sudo** you most certainly know that the default setup will require the user running sudo to enter a password (by default the password of the user running sudo and not the *root password*).
In Ubuntu, if you wish to remove a user from the *admin* group, run this command in a terminal:

```
gpasswd -d username admin
```

Check it out:

```
id -Gn username
```

You should see something like that:

```
username adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

without the *admin* privilege.

Comment: _you most certainly know that the default setup will require the user running sudo to enter a password_ **this is not true**, every user can change their pw by typing 'passwd'. I would like to know how to prevent a normal user to execute that command.