# Prevent user from executing history -c command in shell

Tags: command-line, history

Is it possible to prevent specific user from executing `history -c` command in shell.

Comment: This is quite a difficult problem. Ultimately, the user could always create a script and run that, commands executed from a script are not logged.

Answer (score 0):

`history` command is a bash builtin command (you can find it somewere at the line 4348 in `man bash`). So you can use [something like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/108027/147044) in this case.

What you can do is to harden `/home/username/.bash_history` by making it append-only:

```
sudo chattr +a /home/username/.bash_history
```

Also, you have to harden history environment variables by adding the following lines to `/home/username/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s histappend 
readonly PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a" 
readonly HISTFILE 
readonly HISTFILESIZE 
readonly HISTSIZE 
readonly HISTCMD 
readonly HISTCONTROL 
readonly HISTIGNORE
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/308882/secured-bash-history-usage.

Comment: What do you mean by "So you can use something like this in this case."? If it's a builtin, there will be no file to `chmod`. As from your source, you should also set the various bash profile files to read only.

Comment: What is stopping the user from editing `.bashrc` to remove those lines? It should be set to append as well.

Comment: You could `chown` them all to root, but I'm not sure if that will have further consequences.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to Radu's answer, this will `chown` all the bash related files to root then give other users read only access (except `.bash_history` and `.bashrc`, for which they will have read and append premissions)

Add these lines to `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s histappend 
readonly PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a" 
readonly HISTFILE 
readonly HISTFILESIZE 
readonly HISTSIZE 
readonly HISTCMD 
readonly HISTCONTROL 
readonly HISTIGNORE
```

Then execute these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo chown root /home/$USER/.bash_history 
sudo chown root /home/$USER/.bash_profile 
sudo chown root /home/$USER/.bash_login
sudo chown root /home/$USER/.profile
sudo chown root /home/$USER/.bash_logout
sudo chown root /home/$USER/.bashrc

sudo chmod o+rwt     /home/$USER/.bash_history 
sudo chmod o+rt,a+x  /home/$USER/.bash_profile 
sudo chmod o+rt,a+x  /home/$USER/.bash_login
sudo chmod o+rt,a+x  /home/$USER/.profile
sudo chmod o+rwt,a+x /home/$USER/.bash_logout
sudo chmod o+rwt,a+x /home/$USER/.bashrc

sudo chattr +a /home/$USER/.bash_history 
sudo chattr +a /home/$USER/.bash_logout
sudo chattr +a /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

**Warning:** Not tested at all, this is provided with **`ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY`**!